# Data structure to check if number of elements is equal in O(1) time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the best data structure to check if the number of elements of different types of objects is the same?

For example, if I have

2 a's

3 b's

3 c's

The number of elements of the different types of objects is not the same.

If I have

2 a's

2 b's

2 c's

then this is the same.

What is the best data structure that allows you do this in O(1) time and how would you implement it?

Comment: You will need to check whether this condition holds after every insert/delete and store the result in a member. Otherwise, you'd always have to calculate the number of elements of each type and compare them, which is at best linear, at worst difficult if the number of types is variable.

Comment: Need some more requirements on the "data structure". As @G.Bach says, you could have a data structure calculate this on the fly, in which case, the answer is already done, but that is somewhat cheating, since you burned CPU cycles creating the data structure (say in a dictionary, at O(n log n) time) instead of querying the data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use two dictionaries to be able to do it in O(1) dynamically.

The first maps each type to a count, {a:2,b:3,c:3}. The second maps each count to a set of types with that count. {2:{a},3:{b,c}}. If the size of the second dictionary is less than 2 (0 or 1) then clearly all types have the same count as if that was not the case then there would be at least two key-item pairs in that dictionary, presuming that the dictionary is updated when the counts change.

- Adding a type just means adding it to each dictionary.
- Removing a type just means removing it from each dictionary.
- Updating a type requires first updating the second dictionary by removing the previous count (obtained from the first dictionary) and adding the current count, after which the first dictionary is updated.

Comment: +1. Although you don't need to store the types in the second dictionary if you just want to check that all types have the same count.

Comment: @justhalf: I'm guessing you actually mean the first dictionary, as that's the only one that may be redundant. To update a count, you remove the type from it's old count set and then add it to it's new count set. That requires that you know the previous count which you get from the first dictionary, meaning you update the first dictionary after updating the second. Though the first dictionary would be redundant if you can get the previous count another way.

Comment: I really meant the second one. You just need to map the count to the number of types which have that count. So first dictionary is `{a:2, b:3, c:3}` and second dictionary is `{2:1, 3:2}`. This way you just need to update the first count, then decrease old count by one, and increase new count by one. Note that you can store the old count in an temporary variable before updating the first one. So you can update the second dictionary.

Comment: @justhalf: Ah, I misread what you had typed. Fair enough, though you loose some information that might be useful that way. Then again, it might also be useless. Depends on the application. Your suggest is certainly more efficient though.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added "if you *just* want to check that all types have the same count" and do not care which types are the same.

Comment: In C++ a dictionary would be like a unordered_map, right?

Comment: @user2612743: Based on this [reference guide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<Type, int> typeCounts = new Dictionary<Type, int>();

// read and store type counts

Type type = typeof(A);

if (typeCounts.Contains(type))
{
 typeCounts[type]++;
}
else
{
 typeCounts.Add(type, 1);
}

// populate type counts by type and finally:

if (typeCounts[typeA] == typeCounts[typeB])
{
 // so on
}
```